# How to get a horizontal scrollbar in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm learning Tkinter at the moment.  From my book, I get the following code for producing a simple vertical scrollbar:

```
from tkinter import * # Import tkinter

class ScrollText:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() # Create a window
        window.title("Scroll Text Demo") # Set title

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame1)
        scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        text = Text(frame1, width = 40, height = 10, wrap = WORD,
                    yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
        text.pack()
        scrollbar.config(command = text.yview)

        window.mainloop() # Create an event loop

ScrollText() # Create GUI
```

which produces the following nice output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsNYI.png)

However, when I then try to change this code in the obvious way to get a horizontal scrollbar, it's producing a weird output.  Here's the code I'm using

```
from tkinter import * # Import tkinter

class ScrollText:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() # Create a window
        window.title("Scroll Text Demo") # Set title

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame1)
        scrollbar.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = X)
        text = Text(frame1, width = 40, height = 10, wrap = WORD,
                    xscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
        text.pack()
        scrollbar.config(command = text.xview)

        window.mainloop() # Create an event loop

ScrollText() # Create GUI
```

and here's what I get when I run this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whI7g.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're assigning horizontal scrolling, `xscrollcommand`, to a vertical `scrollbar`. You need to modify [`Scrollbar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm)'s `orient` option to `'horizontal'` which is by default `'vertical'`.

Try replacing:

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame1)
```

with:

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame1, orient='horizontal')
```

Comment: Awesome.  That does it.  TY.

Comment: @Will.Im.Not No problem.