# Correct image processing on an already modified photo

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I mean a scroll bar that would allow you to preview the next operations. I will include lines for this example and a pictorial image. Referring to another topic and trying to solve it, I have a question. Dante would not describe what is happening in the development environment and it's hard to see without a map.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

history = []  # image:im , "process": p1|p2|cvt|inv|canny|...   or what you want }


def showImage(canvas):
    im_canvas = Image.fromarray(canvas)
    imtk_canvas = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_canvas)

    lbl = Label(image=imtk_canvas)
    lbl.image = imtk_canvas
    lbl.pack(side="left", padx=8, pady=8)


def fSave():
    savepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    cv2.imwrite(savepath, history[-1]["image"])


def fOpen():
    if len(history) > 0:
        history.clear()
        print(history)

    openpath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if os.path.isfile(openpath):

        canvas = cv2.imread(openpath)
        canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        history.insert(0, ({"image": canvas, "process": "openfile"}))
        showImage(canvas)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(
            title="File open Error", message="The file does not exists!")


def func1():
    canvas = history[0]["image"]  # i tried 0 or -
    print("from history type,shape ", type(canvas), canvas.shape)

    canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    canvas = cv2.Canny(canvas, 30, 70)

    # history.insert(0, ({"image": im2, "process": "func1"}))
    history.insert(0,({"image": canvas, "process": "func1"}))
    #history.append({"image": canvas, "process": "func1"})
    showImage(canvas)


def func2():
    canvas = history[0]["image"]

    canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    canvas = 255 - canvas
    canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    history.insert(0,({"image": canvas, "process": "func2"}))
    showImage(canvas)

def set_scrollregion(self, event):
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

def ini():
    root = Tk()

    canvas = Canvas(root)
    canvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
    xscrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
    xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)

    frame = Frame(canvas)
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor=NW)
    frame.bind('<Configure>', set_scrollregion)

    menubar = Menu(root)

    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Load", command=fOpen)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=fSave)
    filemenu.add_command(label="func1", command=func1)
    filemenu.add_command(label="func2", command=func2)

    filemenu.add_separator()

    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

    root.config(menu=menubar)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ini()
```

I have studied the topic, I have dug up half of the internet, documentation and there is progress, but I usually try to eliminate bugs. So that it could be scrolled sideways.

Comment: If you want to modify current loaded image, you should not call `imread()` to load the image again inside `func1()` and `func2()`.

Comment: I understand it seems obvious. I put code that works and reduced to the maximum. I have tried many ways, but there is a problem with modifying an image that has already been processed. I searched, but did not find a solution that, for example, copies an image from panel2 to panel1 without first loading an image from a file. @acw1668

Comment: @acw1668 What do you think about it? stackoverflow.com/a/65845076/13842923 Maybe because I am sitting on it for quite a long time, I do not notice certain things. Anyway, there are many problems, not only with Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

history=[] #image:im , "process": p1|p2|cvt|inv|canny|...   or what you want }

def showImage(canvas,lbl,side="left"):

    im_canvas = Image.fromarray(canvas)
    imtk_canvas = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_canvas)
    '''
    lbl = Label(image=imtk_canvas)
    lbl.image = imtk_canvas
    lbl.pack(side="left", padx=8, pady=8)
    '''

    lbl.image = imtk_canvas
    lbl.configure(image=imtk_canvas)
    lbl.pack(side="left", padx=8, pady=8)


def fSave():    
    savepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    cv2.imwrite(savepath, history[-1]["image"])


def fOpen(lbl,lbox):

    openpath = filedialog.askopenfilename()    
    if os.path.isfile(openpath):     

        canvas = cv2.imread(openpath)
        canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        
        hid = len(history)
        history.append({"image":canvas,"process":"fOpen"})
        lbox.insert(END, f"HistoryID:{hid} - fOpen:{openpath}") 
        lbox.pack()

        showImage(canvas,lbl,"bottom")

    else:
        messagebox.showerror(
                title="File open Error" , message="The file does not exists!")

def func1(lbl,lbox):
        
        canvas = history[-1]["image"]
        print("from history type,shape ",type(canvas),canvas.shape)

        canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        canvas = cv2.Canny(canvas, 30, 70)

        hid = len(history)
        history.append({"image":canvas,"process":"func1"})
        lbox.insert(END, f"HistoryID:{hid} - func1") 
        lbox.pack()


        showImage(canvas,lbl)

def func2(lbl,lbox):

        canvas = history[-1]["image"]

        canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        canvas = 255 - canvas        
        canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        hid = len(history)
        history.append({"image":canvas,"process":"func2"})
        lbox.insert(END, f"HistoryID:{hid} - func2") 
        lbox.pack()

        showImage(canvas,lbl)

def ini():

    root = Tk()

    lbox = Listbox(root, width = 640, height = 5 )
    lbox.pack()

    lbl1 = Label(root)
    lbl1.pack()
    
    lbl2 = Label(root)
    lbl2.pack()


    menubar = Menu(root)

    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Load",  command=lambda:fOpen(lbl1,lbox))
    filemenu.add_command(label="Save",  command=fSave)
    filemenu.add_command(label="func1", command=lambda:func1(lbl2,lbox))
    filemenu.add_command(label="func2", command=lambda:func2(lbl2,lbox))

    filemenu.add_separator()

    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

    root.config(menu=menubar)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ini()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: i added a new version ... only two label for all the images. first for opened images, and second for processed image. Every process are stored in hystory and a ListBox show you every process you run editing the images. So you can load another image if you want and continue ..

Comment: I did not find information in the documentation, internet or example. I am glad that you are giving me your time. I mean the situation that I described in the modified first post. I spent so much time on that that the next modifications may show up and it's cool. The problem is how to scroll the application window horizontally to be able to scroll through the next effects? I saw examples with text, but didn't find the "widening" of the picture window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954758/how-to-get-a-horizontal-scrollbar-in-tkinter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49873626/create-list-of-image-with-scrollable-bar-for-tkinter/49883085

Comment: Here a good simple tutorial about Gui python programming  with Tkinter.  I can't spend much effort to this post .  If any of the answers were helpful for you, please vote high.  It was a pleasure.  Good Luck ! https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm

Comment: Fine. Nice, because you directed me to many things, but if you could have a look at the updated first post in your free moment. I think this is a minor thing because I mean the solution as simple as possible. It does not have to stop anything, it is enough to be able to scroll to the right side.

Answer (score 0):

In this example you can change the image of the same Label ...

```
# It would be better to open new questions with new posts to address different problems.
```

from somewhere on Stack Overflow (sorry)

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

path1='images/test1.png'
path2='images/test2.png'

root = tk.Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path1))
panel = tk.Label(root, image=img)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

def callback(e):
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path2))
    panel.configure(image=img2)
    panel.image = img2

root.bind("<Return>", callback)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have studied the topic, I have dug up half of the internet, documentation and there is progress, but I usually try to eliminate bugs. Take a look at the answer as it is rather a small matter to start a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

I mean a scroll bar that would allow you to preview the next operations. I will include lines for this example and a pictorial image. Dante would not describe what is happening in the development environment and it's hard to see without a map.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

history = []  # image:im , "process": p1|p2|cvt|inv|canny|...   or what you want }


def showImage(canvas):
    im_canvas = Image.fromarray(canvas)
    imtk_canvas = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_canvas)

    lbl = Label(image=imtk_canvas)
    lbl.image = imtk_canvas
    lbl.pack(side="left", padx=8, pady=8)


def fSave():
    savepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    cv2.imwrite(savepath, history[-1]["image"])


def fOpen():
    if len(history) > 0:
        history.clear()
        print(history)

    openpath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if os.path.isfile(openpath):

        canvas = cv2.imread(openpath)
        canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        history.insert(0, ({"image": canvas, "process": "openfile"}))
        showImage(canvas)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(
            title="File open Error", message="The file does not exists!")


def func1():
    canvas = history[0]["image"]  # i tried 0 or -
    print("from history type,shape ", type(canvas), canvas.shape)

    canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    canvas = cv2.Canny(canvas, 30, 70)

    # history.insert(0, ({"image": im2, "process": "func1"}))
    history.insert(0,({"image": canvas, "process": "func1"}))
    #history.append({"image": canvas, "process": "func1"})
    showImage(canvas)


def func2():
    canvas = history[0]["image"]

    canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    canvas = 255 - canvas
    canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    history.insert(0,({"image": canvas, "process": "func2"}))
    showImage(canvas)


def ini():
    root = Tk()

    h = Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal')

    h.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    menubar = Menu(root)

    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Load", command=fOpen)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=fSave)
    filemenu.add_command(label="func1", command=func1)
    filemenu.add_command(label="func2", command=func2)

    filemenu.add_separator()

    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

    root.config(menu=menubar)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ini()
```

[sample effect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddgBB.png)